# asp.net changing website root

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

I am URL routing myself.
Main project only contain the URL routing code.
Different websites are placed on approot.
e.g: I have deployed VS2010 test-default-website at approot/webTest/.
I am trying to opening http://webTest/Account/Login.aspx from browser.
For that URL request, I am serving page using PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(), as follows:

In URL route request handler,

return PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance("webTest/Account/Login.aspx", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("webTest/Account/Login.aspx"),
                                                HttpContext.Current);

I am getting following exception:

The file '/Account/webTest/Account/Login.aspx' does not exist.

PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance is automatically appending '/Account' before the  actual address, thus unable to find it.
How can I make it not to append '/Account' ?

Thank you.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"webTest/Account/Login.aspx"` is a relative path, add a slash to beginning to make it absolute: `"/webTest/Account/Login.aspx"`

Comment: Thank you very much Artem :D, you have save my day :)